# How to change 'None' in admin to ''

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I do in order to disable None in my table, the table AUTORDOCUMENT only have foreign keys.

I tried in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin.views import main

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super(MyModelAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         main.EMPTY_CHANGELIST_VALUE = ''
```

but I'm still getting None

models.py

```
class AutorDocument(models.Model):  
     idAuthor=models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,verbose_name ='Author')  

   document=models.ForeignKey(Document,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,verbose_name='title')

    def __str__(self):
        return  unicode(self.idAutor)+' Titulo tesis: '+ unicode(self.tesis)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(('%s %s' % (self.idAutor,self.tesis) ))

class Author(models.Model):
    Firtname=models.CharField(max_length=50)    
    middlename=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    secondsurname=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastName=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
       return  unicode(self.lastName)+' '+ 
       unicode(self.secondsurname)+' '+unicode(self.Firtname)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return smart_unicode(('%s %s %s %s' % 
       (self.Firtname,self.middlename,self.secondsurname,self.lastName) ))

class Document(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(('%s' % (self.titulo) ))
```

author and document are the models that are being referenced by AuthorDocument

[image: table AUTORdocument]

Comment: You need to show your model, particularly the fields and the `__str__` method.

Comment: I realise the error, I have to delete the `self.middlename`, from my model Author

Comment: @AshMGM you can keep it, have a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Author(models.Model):
    Firtname = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    secondsurname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{lname} {sname} {fname}'.format(
            lname=self.lastName or '',
            sname=self.secondsurname or '',
            fname=self.Firtname or ''
        )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_unicode(str(self))
```